# CRM 2011 - How to disable JS library?

Tags: javascript, entity, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

AFAIK in CRM 2011 there is only the possibility to disalbe a JS function for a field.
Is there also a way to disable a single JS library on a form?

Comment: Can't you just remove the JS webresource in your solution?

Comment: ...or less "aggressively", manually detach it from your form at design time.

Answer (score 1):

Is this for development purposes only, or is it going into production? If for development, you can use one of any number of browser-based script blocking plugins (noscript plugins etc.) and selectively block / enable scripts.

If for production, you can write a script that removes the offending  tag from the DOM after the DOM is loaded. This could be problematic, and unsupported as others have indicated, but it is under the assumption that the core CRM 2011 script code is not accessible (or removable) to developers. Example code (using jQuery for simplification):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('script[src="url_to_offending_script_here"]').remove();
});
```

Comment: Implied from @Joshua's answer, but this would be an **unsupported** customisation therefore should be discouraged.